# Error reported when using Pod to access CallKits SDK of ZEGOCLOUD

Tags: zegocloud

I want to use ZEGOCLOUD's Call Kits SDK. When I access it according to their [development documentation](https://docs.zegocloud.com/article/14823), Pod install reports an error.

Podfile:

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'CallKitsDemo' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for CallKitsDemo
  pod 'ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCall'
  pod 'ZegoUIKitSignalingPlugin'

end
```

Error after executing `Pod install`

```
Analyzing dependencies
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:228:in `initialize_from_file': [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (56). (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1190:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1189:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1189:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Ruby has compatibility issues with the latest version of Xcode, and you need to set the project's format to support earlier versions of Xcode.

[image]